# Module import or export statement unexpected here

Tags: javascript, import, microsoft-edge

I have problem with importing JS scripts from code. I have a `canvas` game, and want to import my classes rather than define they in HTML. But when I run my code in Edge, it throws me an error.

init.js

```
import {Tram} from "./tram/tram"

var body;
var curScreen = "menu";
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 1920;
canvas.height = 1080;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tex = {};
var corrHeight = 
loadTextures();

window.onload = function () {
    body = document.body;
    body.appendChild(canvas);

    window.onclick = function () {
        if (body.requestFullscreen) {
            body.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (body.msRequestFullscreen) {
            body.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (body.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            body.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (body.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    };

    mainLoop();
};

function updateCanvasRect() {
    canvas.width = brect.width;
    canvas.height = brect.height;
    var prop = 16 / 9;
    tex.sky.img.height = brect.height;
    tex.sky.img.width = brect.height * prop;
    tex.sky.patt = ctx.createPattern(tex.sky.img, "repeat-x");
}

function loadTextures() {
    tex.sky = importTexture("base/sky");
}
```

I have following folder structure:

```
  ts2d/
    img/
      ...
    base/
      ...
      tram/
        tram.js
        ...
      init.js
      load.js
    main.js
    index.html
```

Comment: Which version of Edge?

Comment: 16, with exp. features enabled

Comment: Any more context you can provide? There isn't really much to go on here. e.g. Can you post the full error message / stacktrace? Is the line you listed in `init.js` where the error originates?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen I'm just getting this error on line 1 (where I import my class)
`SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here`

Comment: Are other imports working? Try adding the `.js` suffix to the import statement

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I don't have other imports, adding `.js` not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved! The problem was in HTML script declaration:

I used this code:

```
<script src="base/init.js"></script>
```

But I don't knew, that I need to specify `type` attribute, with code below `import` works excellent!

```
<script src="base/init.js" type="module"></script>
```

UPD: variables just are file-scoped, to use in another file export variables:

```
var myVar = "string";
export {myVar};
```

and then in your file

```
import {myVar} from "<file>";
```

Comment: I tried adding type="module" but now my script won't trigger anymore.